# Simple eigenvalue and matrix multiplication question

Tags: linear-algebra

If A, B are square matrices with positive eigenvalues, does A * B also have positive eigenvalues?

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -6 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$AB = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -6 & -4 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The spectra are as follows:

$$\sigma(A) = \{ 1, 1 \}, \quad \sigma(B) = \{ 1, 2 \}, \quad \sigma(AB) = \{ -2, -1 \}.$$